# Castle Windsor - could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

Ok- so I have been banging my head against my desk for 3 hours now.

We've recently decided to move away from a Sharepoint .NET 3.5 based system to MVC3 .NET 4.0 - good move.

Initially I created a new project. I created a clone of our existing libraries such as core, data, services and utilities and configured a custom fabric project using Castle Windsor IoC to bind everything together. Great - everything is working as expected.

One thing I decided to change was that Sharepoint required dll's be signed and in the GAC. I didn't really require this any more so I removed this setting and the snk files from each project. I also wanted to upgrade the projects from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 so I changed the target framework fixed a few errors and it's now building fine.

For some reason I'm getting the following error when Windsor tries to install it's components

```
windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer()
    .Install(FromAssembly.This()); //looks for types of IWindsorInstaller in this assembly
```

Could not load file or assembly 'Company.Utility, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've literally tried everything I can think of. Cleared all bin folders and rebuilt. Cleared my gac windows\assembly, cleared temp asp.net files, iis reset.

I'm sure it must be some sort of caching problem but I just can't see a way through it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the Assembly Binding Log Viewer tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I've decided to revert my changes and take a more staggered approach. The error should happen again so when I find out what the cause was I'll update this thread.